# angularjs resolve promise before controllers starts

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking for a way to resolve my promise before the controller starts kicking in.
But whatever I try, the controller is already running and the result is still waiting.
Can anyone help me :(

```
templateUrl: 'tag/details.html',
resolve: {
    result: function (TagResource, $route) {
        TagResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise.then(function (data) {
            return data
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is this an ui-router state?

Comment: What I can see from first sight is that you are not returning from your resolver. Try with `return TagResource.get()...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the promise:

```
templateUrl: 'tag/details.html',
resolve: {
    result: function (TagResource, $route) {
        ̶T̶a̶g̶R̶e̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶.̶g̶e̶t̶(̶{̶ ̶i̶d̶:̶ ̶$̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶.̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶.̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶s̶.̶i̶d̶ ̶}̶)̶
        return TagResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id })
        .$promise.then(function (data) {
            return data
        });
    }
}
```

---

BETTER YET

Skip the `.then` method:

```
templateUrl: 'tag/details.html',
resolve: {
    result: function (TagResource, $route) {
        ̶T̶a̶g̶R̶e̶s̶o̶u̶r̶c̶e̶.̶g̶e̶t̶(̶{̶ ̶i̶d̶:̶ ̶$̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶.̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶.̶p̶a̶r̶a̶m̶s̶.̶i̶d̶ ̶}̶)̶
        return TagResource.get({ id: $route.current.params.id }).$promise;
    }
}
```